# Why does my Apache redirect everything?

Tags: macos, apache, redirect

This concerns an old website which somebody else set up a long time ago, running on apache 1 on a mac system.

Now, this should be replaced and I have redirected all requests to a new website via .htaccess files (RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*)$) and forgot, that there is still one project in a subfolder, that must remain accessible. However, this mistake I can't seem to undo. I have deleted the .htaccess-file - still redirected -, recreated an empty one - still redirected - and restarted the apache. Still, I am redirected to the new webpage. What has happened? How can I find out?

Thanks a lot,
Dinah

---

edit:

I have checked very often now. It always tells me, the .htaccess files didn't exist anymore. I tried to

```
sudo find . -name .htaccess
```

it. In some subfolders, there are .htaccess-files that I did never touch. 
I have edited /etc/httpd/httpd.conf to say

```
AccessFileName .htaccessory
```

restarted

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

and still was redirected.
(Doubted everything and thought about better going to sleep...)

My httpd.conf is too long, how can I post it?

Comment: Tripple check, and then again. You cetainly did _not_ really remove the .htaccess file. Oh, and check if there is a proxy involved.

Comment: Not sure...can you look at your access log and error log to see if there are any clues?

Comment: Also switching on rewrite debugging is a good idea in such cases.

Comment: Can you paste your Apache httpd config?

Comment: How would I find out that a Proxy was involved? (And isn't it unlikely, as I have seen this subfolder-webpage today and it disappeared only after I messed with those .htaccess-files?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Browser must have cached the site. I changed the machine I am testing on and everything shows up, no redirecting at all. Astonishing first, as I remember restarting firefox when things started to become confusing. Astonishing second, as I can't get any redirects to work *at all* now. I'd say, the problem is solved way too good. My .htaccess-file looks like:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/subsite(.*)$ http://newpage.de/subsite
```

that's okay, right? But it doesn't work. Oh man. Well, it's late, I guess. Thanks a lot, everybody and sorry for asking.

Best Greetings, Dinah

Comment: Permanent redirects (301) are cached very aggressively by browsers. While testing use temporary redirects (302), then once everything is working switch to permanent.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks a very, very lot, Gerben! That was really annoying.